# Geoserver-WFS : filter PropertyIsEqualTo not working with bbox

Tags: wfs

I am new to geoserver, I have setup the geoserver which provides the result in below format when I use the wfs service,

```
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "test.1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [[124.97017655, -34.80818888], [184.02247243, -62.90140597]]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geometry",
           "properties": {
                "id": "1",
                "abc_id": "1840350675",
                "name": "test",
              
            }
        },
        {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "test.2",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [[144.97017655, -34.80818888], [154.02247243, -65.90140597]]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geometry",
            "properties": {
                "id": "2",
                "abc_id": "1840350677",
                "name": "test1",
              
            }
        }
        }]
```

I want to perform the search on property 'name', where I should get the record with only name 'test'.
after the multiple research, I found that I can use filter option with bbox to perform the search on geoserver with wfs as below, but I am not getting correct result after filter.
Looks like it is not filtering with property name, can someone please suggest the way to perform the search with bbox + filter.

sharing query here which i amusing to filter the records on geoserver

```
    http://localhost:8888/geoserver/myproject/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mv_testlayer&outputFormat=application/json&fo0rmat_options=callback:getJson&filter=(<Within><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>name</PropertyName><Literal>test</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo><gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>161.3776580 </gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>44.8219 -80.2693</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></Within)
```

Comment: This has nothing to actually do with GeoServer, its a general WFS issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this doesn't work is that the Geometry of a feature is **not** a property of the feature. Properties are (usually) simpler objects like numbers or strings of text. It also fails as you attempt to close the `PropertyIsEqualTo` tag with a `/Within` tag.

To understand filtering with 2.0.0 WFS servers you should at least glance at the [Filter Encoding Specification  (FES)](https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html) where you will learn of the [`BBOX` filter](https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html#60) which is what you actually want:

> The `fes:BBOX` element is defined as a convenient and more compact way of encoding the very common bounding box constraint based on the `gml:Envelope` geometry. It is equivalent to the spatial operation `<fes:Not><fes:Disjoint> … </fes:Disjoint></fes:Not>` meaning that the `fes:BBOX` operator shall identify all geometries that spatially interact with the box.

You probably also need to know about [logical operators to combine queries](https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html#figure_8) such as `and` and `or`.

Finally, there is almost an exact [example of exactly what you are trying to do](https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html#43):

> ```
> <fes:Filter>
>   <fes:And>
>      <fes:Function name="ClassifiedAs">
>         <fes:Literal>RoadTaxonomy</fes:Literal>
>         <fes:Literal>Major Highway</fes:Literal>
>      </fes:Function>
>      <fes:BBOX>
>         <fes:ValueReference>/RS1/geometry</fes:ValueReference>
>         <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::1234http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/epsg/0/1234">
>            <gml:lowerCorner>10 10</gml:lowerCorner>
>            <gml:upperCorner>20 20</gml:upperCorner>
>         </gml:Envelope>
>      </fes:BBOX>
>   </fes:And>    </fes:Filter>
> ```